# bluetooth low energy advertising packet and topology

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to advertise a single id lets say "stackoverflow1" on a ble device. So people close to the sensor can get this message (welcome to wwdc2012) as popups on the iPhone. That's it! meaning that there is no update on the value or anything else in other words I just want to know which room I came in. In another room there's another sensor adversing "stackoverflow2".

Now the question is, should I put the rooms' sensor (advertiser) as Peripherals and visitors' iPhones as Centrals?

If your answer is yes, can I send this Id in advertising packet? i.e. can I skip connection to the room's peripheral? Please guide me a little but on this

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the iPhones should be centrals and the in-room device should be a peripheral. It's perfectly fine to put enough data in the advertisement that the iOS app can do something useful after simply seeing the peripheral advertised without actually connecting to it. That way, multiple centrals/phones can detect proximity at once without a single phone tying up an exclusive connection to the device. Instead of specifying the room in the service name, you should be able to put it in the advertisement data for the device, giving them all the same service name. That way the iOS app doesn't need to know the completely list of rooms (i.e. services) in advance and they can be added to without changing the app.

In short, the gist of what you described should work fine, and seems like a sound approach to me.

Comment: This is the best answer one could have given to me. Thanks a lot. I hope you can also point me to the right direction on how to put the data in in the advertisement data. Because apple for some reason does not provide class reference for CBPeripheral in core bluetooth. There you can only find CBPheripheralDelegate.

Answer (score 4):

You can include information in the advertisement from the peripheral as "Manufacturer Specific" data.  Then the iOS application can get it from the advertisement data dictionary using the CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think you can use that key. From the documentation:advertisementData
An optional dictionary containing the data you want to advertise. The possible keys of an advertisementData dictionary are detailed in CBCentralManagerDelegate Protocol Reference. That said, only two of the keys are supported for peripheral manager objects: CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey and CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey.

Comment: Remember that in my case, the phone is Central and it is connecting to a peripheral.  The peripheral populates the CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey with data and I am pulling that key from the advertisement data without issue. e.g.: `NSData* versionInfo = [advertisementData objectForKey:CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey];`